# Is there a specific name for a square matrix with block of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this form of matrix,

\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & b & 0 & c & 0  \\
0 & a & 0 & b & 0 & c \\
d & 0 & e & 0 & f & 0 \\
0 & d & 0 & e & 0 & f \\
g & 0 & h & 0 & p & 0 \\
0 & g & 0 & h & 0 & p
\end{pmatrix}

I would like to know whether there is a specific name for this matrix?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For 
\begin{pmatrix}
a&0\\
0&a
\end{pmatrix}

We usually call it $aI_2$, which denotes a scalar $a$ times the identity matrix of dim $2$. This type of matrix is also called scalar matrices.

Your matrix can be expressed using the block matrix method:

\begin{pmatrix}
aI_2&bI_2&cI_2\\
dI_2&eI_2&fI_2\\
gI_2&hI_2&pI_2\\
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: It's also written as $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)\otimes \left(\begin{array}{cccc} a & b&c\\d&e&f \\ g&h&p \end{array}\right)$.

Comment: @westerbaan Sure. Using the tensor product the matrix is much easier to represent, but I am not sure whether he understands tensor product or not. Thank you very much.